Azure Logic App HTTP WebHook not waiting for callback
I'm running into an error where I see an HTTP Request Limit timeout after 8 minutes or so of running my logic app at this workflow step. It seems that it is not waiting for the callback URL. I've tested locally and I get a 202 when I post to this endpoint, which the logic app should be getting as well.
{
  "type": "HttpWebhook",
  "inputs": {
    "subscribe": {
      "method": "POST",
      "uri": "https://myapi.com/Endpoint",
      "headers": {
        "CallbackURL": "@{listCallbackUrl()}"
      }
    },
    "retryPolicy": {
      "type": "none"
    }
  },
  "runAfter": {},
  "limit": {
    "timeout": "PT2H"
  }
}

I've tried running remote debugger on VS2022 with the API I am calling and making this call. When I make the POST request from fiddler it runs as expected, with a 202, and then later posts to my callbackURL. When the logic app makes the call, it sees the 202, but does not wait for the callbackURL to be posted to, instead erroring out with an http request limit timeout.


Azure Logic App HTTP WebHook not waiting for callback

As an alternative, One way of waiting for callback is making the http action asynchronous.

Now the http action will wait until it gets 202 status code.
Another alternative way is by using 2 Logic app workflows, In one it call http request and the callback should send the message to queue or topic or blob , In second we can use trigger like blob or queue in Logic app and whenever new message or blob comes take the message do the next actions after that.
1st Logic app:

The API gets called and send the response to service bus in my example .
2nd Logic app:

When API send the message this logic app triggers and get the status code and later do the next steps or actions of yours.
